# Can't read .mat file saved using scipy version 1.2.1 using scipy 1.4.1

Tags: python, scipy

I have saved a few .mat files in Python using scipy.io.savemat with scipy version 1.4.1. When I try to read these files on another machine using scipy.io.loadmat with scipy version 1.2.1, I get the following error:
`ValueError: Unknown mat file type, version 0, 1`

Is this caused because of version differences between 1.2.1 and 1.4.1? How can I get past this issue without having to install different versions of Scipy?

Thanks

Comment: You might try `savemat(...., format='4')`.  But that's available in 1.2.1 as well; so it might not matter.  I don't see anything else in the docs that suggest a change.  The supported MATLAB formats, `v4 (Level 1.0), v6 and v7 to 7.2 matfiles are supported.` have around for quite some time. (the format choice goes back to 0.10 or earlier, 2012).

Comment: Looking at `io.matlab.miobase.get_matfile_version` I see that it tries find a bytes that indicates it is v4.  If successful it returns `version 0, 0`.  Failing that it looks for v5 version info, which should be (1,x) or (2,x).  Based on that I can't tell you what was wrong with a file that yielded a (0,1) version.  I don't think it's scipy version issue.